# Create An Array of Array in c#

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, collections

Hi How to create an Array of Arrays like

```
  EDIT: [[1,"aaaaaa",1],[2,"bbbbbbb",2],[3,"ccccccc",3]]
```

from a list

```
IList<TestList>

public class TestList
    {
        public int x{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int y{ get; set; }    

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to do this for deserialization?

Comment: @BhushanFirake - I want this to be passed to a javascript object.

Comment: You want this then:  http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're looking for, this should do the trick:

```
IList<TestList> testList;

public class TestList
{
    public int x{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int y{ get; set; }
}

var newList = testList.Select(t => new object[] { t.x, t.Name, t.y});
var myArrayOfArrays = newList.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks,Please see my Edit in the question. Basically I want array which has both string and int